# requests - how to change location sent?

Tags: python, python-requests

My code works when I make `request` from location machine.
When I try to make the `request` from `AWS EC2` I get the following error:

> requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www1.xyz.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=20)

I tried checking the `url` and that was not the issue. I then went ahead and tried to visit the page using the `url` and hidemyass webproxy with location set to the `AWS EC2` machine, it got a `404`.

The code:

```
# Dummy URL's
header = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36",
        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
    }

url = 'https://www1.xyz.com/iKeys.jsp?symbol={}&date=31DEC2020'.format(
        symbol)
raw_page = requests.get(url, timeout=10, headers=header).text
```

I have tried setting the proxies to another ip address in the `request`, which I searched online:

```
proxies = {
     "http": "http://125.99.100.193",
     "https": "https://125.99.100.193",}
raw_page = requests.get(url, timeout=10, headers=header, proxies=proxies).text
```

Still got the same error.

1- Do I need to specify the port in proxies? Could this be causing the error when proxy is set?

2- What could be a solution for this?

Thanks

Comment: Don't use the `timeout` parameter in your request

Comment: @AdamStrauss tried it, no response for almost 10 minutes.

Comment: Maybe your target URL blocks requests from EC2 hostname/IP address?

Comment: @barny, yes I think its a region problem. i.e. on local machine when I use a hidemyass proxy and set it to region of EC2, the website gives a 404.